# Invalid list literal for <column name> of type frozen<list<bigint>>

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh, frozen-columns

I am having an issue filtering by a column of type frozen> that is part of a clustering key sorted in `DESC` order.

### Context

This is the definition of my keyspace and tables

```
CREATE KEYSPACE hello WITH replication = 
    {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };

CREATE TABLE hello.table1 (
    fn bigint,
    et smallint,
    st frozen<list<bigint>>,
    tn bigint,
    ts timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((fn, et), st, tn));

CREATE TABLE hello.table2 (
    fn bigint,
    et smallint,
    st frozen<list<bigint>>,
    tn bigint,
    ts timestamp,
PRIMARY KEY ((fn, et), st, tn)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (st DESC, tn DESC);
```

---

### What works...

Inserting records into `table1` works fine:

```
INSERT INTO hello.table1(fn, et,st,tn, ts) VALUES ( 1,1,[23],1,0);
INSERT INTO hello.table1(fn, et,st,tn, ts) VALUES ( 1,1,[24],1,0);
INSERT INTO hello.table1(fn, et,st,tn, ts) VALUES ( 1,1,[25],1,0);
```

Selecting records and specifying a frozen column in the `where` clause also works fine

```
select * from hello.table1 where fn=1 and et=1 and st=[23];
```

---

### What does not work...

Inserting records into `table2` does not work:

```
INSERT INTO hello.table2(fn, et,st,tn, ts) VALUES ( 1,1,[23],1,0);
```

And if I already have records inserted (from my application), selecting records and specifying a frozen column in the `where` clause also does not work

```
select * from hello.table2 where fn=1 and et=1 and st=[23];
```

Comment: It looks like a bug. There is no reason why the clustering order would forbid these commands.

Comment: I agree. This only occurs when DESC is specified. If ASC is specified explicitly, it works fine.

Comment: Where is the proper place to report this bug?